# How would you write a character turning invisible?

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy

One of my characters in the story I'm writing has the power of invisibility. I was wondering how it would feel for her to turn invisible from her perspective.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What specifically are you asking? Is it how to visually describe someone turning invisible? The extended perspective of an invisible person?

Comment: Since this doesn't happen in real life, nobody knows - you just have to use your imagination!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is figure out what happens when she turns invisible. Does the light go through her or do the minds of other people somehow no longer take note of her presence? Can she still see herself or is she invisible to herself, too? And so on.

Then you need to come up with a mechanism and its effects. Does the matter of her body change? Or does the light around her change its trajectory?

Depending on your answers, your character may feel nothing or some physical sensation or just happiness or surprise that it works.

Much of your answers will likely depend on the story you want to tell. Is it a story with a light and funny tone? Then the character will have funny feelings. Is it a dark and brooding tale? Then her emotions will be gloomy. And so on.

All these are decisions you as a writer have to make in relation to your story. We cannot write your story for you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends. Your character has the power to turn herself invisible. So if it requires any physical exertion to make herself invisible, then she will feel that exertion. For example, if the effort was the same as running she will feel the effort she makes as if she is running during the time it takes for her to become invisible.

On the other hand, if no effort is involved she experience changes in her perspective as her invisibility takes hold. This will also depend on whether she is invisible from her perspective. For example, the old-time radio version of The Shadow became 'invisible' by means of a form of hypnosis. So he visible in the ordinary sense, but unseen by people who were under his influence.

HG Wells' Invisible Man was actually physically invisible. His body neither absorbed, reflected or emitted any light and its refractive index was adjusted to be the same as the air. Now this kind of invisibility will change his perspective. He can see in all directions, because he see through himself. Wells himself was aware that his version of invisibility had a number of disadvantages and wouldn't be as effective as depicted in his novel.

It is mainly a matter of thinking about how the power of invisibility comes into effect to make them invisible. Whether there are physical effects, whether she has to exert herself or has to concentrate to make her power work or even whether as she becomes invisible there might be bodily sensations. Like her skin tingling as she is disappearing. Many of these things you will have to work out for yourself as the author as they will influence her feelings.

Answer (score 0):

"I squeezed my eyes shut. As I opened them, I did not know what was different. I certainly didn't feel different. But I could run across the road and get hit by a car and people would feel a slight bump while driving over but would otherwise know nothing. I could wreak havoc everywhere and get away with it, and for centuries people would reflect over the wrecker from the underworld, but I would not."
They wouldn't, would they? Or would people not feel the bump either? Would they be recognised by their name in history, by another of their kind that came a milennia after?

Comment: It doesn't usually help the person asking a question on this site if you attempt to write their scene for them. You don't know enough about the story for your scene to fit into what OP wants to write, and your example is too specific for OP to understand what they need to do to come up with a good scene of their own. It is usually better, if you *explain* how you would approach the problem that OP has so they can learn from your.

Comment: @Ben Will keep in mind from now on, thanks!